# Вернуть анонимный тип в Func

Tags: c#

Есть метод, загружающий все внедренные ресурсы из библиотеки по указанному пути.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<(string filePath, string content)>> LoadResourcesAsync(Assembly assembly, string path)
{
    string assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
    var files = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(x => x.StartsWith($"{assemblyName}.{path}"));

    List<(string filePath, string content)> result = new();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
        using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
        string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        result.Add(new(file, content));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Для интереса попробовал переписать foreach на select, но не смог. Код выглядит ужасно и сложно, но что я делаю не так?

```
return files.Select(async (string x, (string filePath, string content)) =>
{
    using Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(x);
    using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
    string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    return (x, content);
});
```

Comment: Как вы понимаете `(string x, (string filePath, string content)`? Возвращаемый объект? Если да, то это не так, ибо до `=>` вы указываете входные параметры `Funс`, а они могут быть либо `x` (объект), либо `(x, i)` (объект, индекс). А вот уже после `=>` вы формируете `TResult` (у вас, например это кортеж (`return (x, content)`)). Исходя из этого, чтоб LINQ был валиден, замените `async (string x, (string filePath, string content))` на простой `async x`. НО! Так, как у вас еще и `async`, то результатом будет коллекция `Task`'ов, из-за чего это все надо обернуть еще и в `await Task.WhenAll(..)`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо! Все работает. Ответ оформите?

Comment: Пожалуй, воздержусь от этого. Можете сделать это самостоятельно, написав то, что вы поняли.

Answer (score 3):

Верный вариант (EvgeniyZ):

```
return await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(async x =>
{
    using Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(x);
    using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
    string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    return (x, content);
}));
```